# Return multiple results from an async method?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

I currently have a method that looks something like this:

```
typedef void MyCallback(int status, String body);


void makeRequest(String url, MyCallback callback) async {
  if( someCondition ){
    callback(1, '');
  }

  Response response = await http.get(url);

  if( response.httpCode == 200 ){
    callback(2, response.body);
  }
  else{
    callback(3, '');
  }
}
```

I want to get rid of the callback so that I can wait for the result(s) of `makeRequest`. But if I simply make it return a `Future`, I won't be able to return more than once.

I looked into using streams, but it seems a bit complicated. So basically I'm looking for something as convenient as a `Future` but that could receive "partial results", i.e. receive a result more than once. To illustrate:

```
MultiFuture<int> makeRequest(String url){
  MultiFuture result = new MultiFuture();

  if( someCondition ){
    result.value(1);
  }

  http.get(url).then((response){
    if( response.httpCode == 200 ){
      result.value(2);
    }
    else{
      result.value(3);
    }

    result.finish();
  });


  return result;
}




MultiFuture requestResult = makeRequest('https://example.com');

await requestResult.onValue((int value){
  print('value: $value');
});      
// When result.finish() is called, the await is finished
```

Is using a stream my best option, or is there some kind of `MultiFuture` that I just don't know about?

Comment: You are just describing streams . Yes, they are a little bit more complicated than futures, but they completely match your use-case and are baked in the language. So just mark your method `async*` and start to  `yield` the results ;).

Answer (score 0):

Return multiple results from an async method is exactly what streams does. Here is an example I made based on your code so it could be easier for you to understand how it works:

```
class MultiFuture {
  StreamController<int> _resultController = StreamController<int>();
  Stream<int> get requestResult => _resultController.stream;

  void makeRequest(String request) async {
    if (true) {
      _resultController.sink.add(1);
    }

    // mock request
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));

    if (true) {
      _resultController.sink.add(2);
    } else {
      _resultController.sink.add(3);
    }
  }

  void example() {
    makeRequest("https://example.com");

    requestResult.listen((value) {
      print('value: $value');
    });
  }
}
```

You can test it calling MultiFuture().example();

---

But I recommend you to see these simple short videos to have a better idea:
[Async Coding With Dart](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjxrf2q8roU0Net_g1NT5_vOO3s_FR02J)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't have time to test this out right now, but what seems to be missing is the ability to `await` some final value or close event, like the `.finish()` in my pseudo code?

Comment: The requestResult.listen will trigger every time _resultController.sink.add is called, that's why you don't need to wait some final value or close an event. Try to play with this code adding prints everywhere, also check the videos that are really simple and well explained. P. S. What you will need to close when you exit the screen is the controller, you should call the resultController.close() inside the dispose() method of the widget state to release the resources