# Flutter Add values to a List<map<String,dynamic>>

Tags: flutter

Is it Possible to add values to a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` from `Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>`.
I'm trying to add more values to a list as the scroll end.

```
 Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> _future;
            List<map<String, dynamic>> resultUrl = [];


                  @override
                  void initState() {
                   _future = fetch()
                    _scrollController.addListener(() {
                      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
                          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
                        getMoreData();
                      }
                });

                super.initState();
              }


         Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> fetch() async {
         http.Response response = await http.get(url);
         if (response.statusCode != 200) return null;
          return List<Map<String, 
           dynamic>>.from(json.decode(response.body)['map']);
          }



//In a stateful Widget

 FutureBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
      future: _future,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          print(snapshot.error);
        } else {
          resultList = snapshot.data;
        }
        return resultList != null?
StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                crossAxisCount: 4,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => new 
                  Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                    child: Card(
                      semanticContainer: true,
                      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                      elevation: 5,
                      child: Image(
                        image: NetworkImage(resultList[index]['image']),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),

                ),
                staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
                    new StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 2 : 1),
                mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
              );

    getMoreData() {
       resultUrl.add(_future);// resultUrl.addAll(_future);
      }
```

Comment: Could you post some code that shows how the ListView is filled?

Comment: @PabloBarrera the code is updated.

Comment: Great, do you have a way to make a request that retrieves only new items?

Comment: Tried many ways but unable to get it.@PabloBarrera

Comment: To get more items to display you will need to make a new request where the response has only the new items, your api will need to be able to be called with parameters like 'page' and 'page_size' for example. Is that possible with the api you are using to get the data?

Comment: Yes it is possible with the api I'm using, but if i create a new method where i can call the new data, how can i add it on the builder?

Comment: I'll be preparing something these days. It would be using streams, so you could try to familiarize with that meanwhile, here is quick example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58292128/return-multiple-results-from-an-async-method/58293092#58293092

Comment: Ok, I'll look into it.