# Flutter: How to show an Indicator under Gridview.count with infinity scroll

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm building a simple app ( some type of blog ) using just flutter no other libraries.

Now, I have Implemented an infinite scroll for new posts with `GridView.count` everything is working fine,

But I need to be there a message and an indicator at the end of the list to tell the user to wait to tell the new content load from the server I can't find a way to implement such a thing on my code!!

The code so far:

```dart
class _BrandsSingle extends State<BrandsSingle> {

  List phones = [];
  ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();
  int pageNumber = 1;
  bool loading = false;

  Future fetchPhonesByBrand(int page) async {

    page = pageNumber;
    loading = true;

    final response = await http.get('http://192.168.1.6:3000/reviews/${widget.id}/$page');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {

      setState(() {
        phones.addAll(jsonDecode(response.body));
        loading = false;
      });

    } else {
      // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    this.fetchPhonesByBrand(pageNumber);
    super.initState();

    _scrollController.addListener( () {
      if ( _scrollController.position.pixels == _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent ) {
        pageNumber++;
        print(pageNumber);
        fetchPhonesByBrand(pageNumber);
      }
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    if ( loading == true ) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.id),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              CircularProgressIndicator(),
              SizedBox( height: 15 ),
              Text(
                "من فضلك أنتظر قليلاً...",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontFamily: 'Mada'
                ),
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(
              widget.id.toUpperCase(),
              style: TextStyle(
                  letterSpacing: 2,
                  fontFamily: 'Mada'
              ),
            )
        ),
        body:  GridView.count(
          controller: _scrollController,
          crossAxisCount: 1,
          children: List.generate(
              phones.length,
                  (int index) {
                var phone = phones[index];

                return Card(
                  child: Ink.image(
                    image: NetworkImage(phone['image']),
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/phone', arguments: phone['id']),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            colors: [Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0), Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.7)],
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only( bottom: 10, left: 10, right: 10 ),
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  'مواصفات ${phone['title'].toString().toUpperCase()}',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontFamily: 'Mada',
                                    letterSpacing: 2,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the loading as last item of your list:

- The `List` length should be `phones.length + 1`
- If `index <= phones.length - 1` you return the `Card` of a normal item
- Otherwise you return the loading widget

You may need to check some edge cases like:

- If the list is empty
- If the list height is smaller than the screen so it won't scroll
- If some requests fail
- If a request doesn't have more items

Comment: Actually, I tried this way and left me with 2 issues, One is the indicator will be always showing under the list ( not if I scroll then show up ), Two the indicator taking a half size of the screen ( because of the GridView )

Comment: When you finish getting data you could hide the loading and when you reach the end of the list you could show it again. I think there is a way to specify different crossAxisCount according to the index of the list, did you check GridView.custom() or GridView.builder() and their gridDelegate properties?

Comment: could you give me a sample code to do so when you get free?

Comment: I'll be preparing something these days. It would be using streams, so you could try to familiarize with that meanwhile, here is quick example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58292128/return-multiple-results-from-an-async-method/58293092#58293092